# Installation problem of custom theme in drupal

Tags: composer-php, themes, drupal-8, drush

I am setting up a dev server with apache, MySQL, and PHP and I installed drupal successfully.

Now I am trying to install this custom theme [https://github.com/openeuropa/oe_theme]
but I have some problems.
I installed global composer and local drush into my drupal site.

As the instructions say I did :

1. `composer require openeuropa/oe_theme`
2. `./vendor/bin/drush en oe_theme_helper`
3. I also inserted this patch (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/474684-151.patch) inside drupal's composer.json
4. `./vendor/bin/drush config-set system.theme default oe_theme`

I run `drush:rebuild` after the theme changed of course ...

From command I run `drush status` and I see default theme: oe_theme but in the site, it looks like is not installed
There is also an error saying that *Drupal\Core\ExtensionUnknownException: The oe_theme does not exist or not installed ...*

Of course, if I try to add content I get *The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.*

Server: Apache (RHEL 7)
MySQL 8
PHP 7.3
Drupal 8.9

It's my first time working with these tools and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone has installed this theme before or just could help me figure this out I would be grateful.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
$ composer require openeuropa/oe_theme
$ composer require openeuropa/composer-artifacts
$ npm install @ecl-twig/ec-components
```

Set theme as default on the site

Enable module Open Europa Theme Helper and all required modules  in /admin/modules

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path : /admin/appearance
Verify that oe_theme is in the list and is set to default.

If this page throws a PHP error:

Verify that the oe_theme files exist in your project physically, if that's not the case try cloning them again.

OR

You might have to enable the oe_theme separately from the oe_theme_helper, this might be a different module.